# Sublime text's auto complete not working properly

Tags: sublimetext

When i enter @section or @extends in sublime text it does not give any suggestion for auto complete, even after typing ctrl+space it says no auto complete available.

in view settings in syntax laravel blade is selected.

I don't know how to get rid of this....???

in user settings autocomplete is true.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned it, I'm going to assume you have the [Laravel 5 Snippets](https://github.com/Lykegenes/laravel-5-snippets) installed (or the equivalent for Laravel 4.) Commonly, snippets contain only alpha-numeric letters, dashes and underscores, though this can be overridden in the `word_separators` setting.

**Default word separators**:

```
"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"
```

To correct triggers for the mentioned snippets are `Blade::section` and `Blade::extends`. Note that these are case-sensitive!